# Does AWS Redshift supports postgis extensions?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift

I know **AWS RDS-postgresql** supports `postgis` extension.
Does **AWS Redshift** support `postgis` extension?

Answer (score 8):

As per this answer was written (June 2016), AWS Redshift itself still does **not** support PostGIS extensions.

The [official documentation](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/c_redshift-and-postgres-sql.html) have not much changed. In [an AWS blog post](https://blogs.aws.amazon.com/bigdata/post/Tx1GQ6WLEWVJ1OX/JOIN-Amazon-Redshift-AND-Amazon-RDS-PostgreSQL-WITH-dblink), it said *implicitly*:

> You can use the dblink extension to connect to Amazon Redshift and leverage PostgreSQL functionality. .... There are likely many other uses for the dblink extension with Amazon Redshift, such as PostGIS or LDAP support in PostgreSQL (Amazon EC2 only), ....

From the above AWS blog post, we can combine Amazon Redshift and RDS/self-hosted PostgreSQL database to make a PostGIS queries by using [dblink](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/static/contrib-dblink-function.html).

If your data is in [latitude-longitude pairs (EPSG-4326/WGS84)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/World_Geodetic_System#A_new_World_Geodetic_System:_WGS_84) format, you can convert your data to single-dimension data using [GeoHash](http://geohash.org/) or [S2 Geometry Library](http://blog.christianperone.com/2015/08/googles-s2-geometry-on-the-sphere-cells-and-hilbert-curve/) hash. Personally, I prefer S2 Geometry Library because it has more precision levels and functionalities. After that, you can make some query over that hash column. And of course, you can combine the result to PostGIS database.

Answer (score 6):

According to AWS docs,

*Amazon Redshift is based on PostgreSQL 8.0.2. Amazon Redshift and PostgreSQL have a number of very important differences that you must be aware of as you design and develop your data warehouse applications.* 
(http://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/c_redshift-and-postgres-sql.html)

*It is not supporting the  basic types that PostGIS depends upon* 
(https://forums.aws.amazon.com/message.jspa?messageID=425664#)

**Therefore, the answer is no.**